# DOM Selector to get text of element ignoring children?

Tags: html, dom, selector

I'm using the [Tab Modifier plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai/related?hl=en) for Chrome to dynamically rename some tabs that I use daily.  In the tab Title definition, it says the following:

> You can inject any DOM content with {selector}. Examples: {title} for website title, {h1}, {#id}, {.class}, etc.

Here is an example of the element I want to use to name the tab:

```
<td class="portalTitleInfoVal">
  PORTALNAME
  <a class="portalLink">Change Portal</a>
</td>
```

This is what I'm currently using for the title:

```
{.portalTitleInfoVal:nth-of-type(4)}
```

But, of course, the tab is named `PORTALNAMEChange Portal`.

How can I modify the DOM selector so that the tab is just named "PORTALNAME"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm really late to the party, but I found this post while searching for an answer.

I'm working with a lot of old systems and all the tabs just says {title}, which is.. not useful when having 15-20 tabs open at once, and it's tedious to hard code every tab.

So.. I brute forced tested until I found a solution:

Every page has a breadcrumb:

```
<div class="breadcrumb noPrint">
  <a href="/XXX/AAA" title="Go to the frontpage.">Home</a> "»" 
  <a href="/XXX/BBB" title="Search materials">Materials</a>
  <a href="/XXX/CCC=123123" title="123123">123123</a>
</div>
```

So they might have updated the extension since, but your guess was very close. I don't know why you were putting in 4, but I assume you had more elements than posted.

Anyhow, the way I got it to work were by:

```
{.breadcrumb  :nth-last-child(2)} : {.breadcrumb :last-child}
```

So, **there has to be a space between the .class and the child element**, which in my case returns Materials : 12312

I haven't tried nearly half, but [DoFactorys list of CSS selectors](https://www.dofactory.com/css/ref/selectors#pseudo-class) were a big help for me.

Answer (score 0):

The element's first child node is the plain text, before the HTML element (`<a>`).

```
$('. portalTitleInfoVal')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

It looks like this plugin will only allow for CSS style element selectors compatible with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). It then grabs the text from that element. From their [github repo](https://github.com/sylouuu/chrome-tab-modifier/blob/master/src/js/content.js#L56):

```
    /**
     * Returns the text related to the given CSS selector
     * @param selector
     * @returns {string}
     */
    getTextBySelector = function (selector) {
        var el = document.querySelector(selector), value = '';

        if (el !== null) {
            value = el.innerText || el.textContent;
        }

        return value.trim();
    };
```

Comment: Any guesses as to how to convert that to the plugin's `{}` syntax?

Comment: Ah, I don't think that will be possible. Looking over the code, it's expecting a CSS style selector only. It then gets the text from that element via `value = el.innerText || el.textContent;`. https://github.com/sylouuu/chrome-tab-modifier/blob/master/src/js/content.js#L56

Comment: Bummer, I'll submit a feature request.  Can you update your answer to include this explanation?  Thanks.